# Methods for creating a very animated webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Afternoon all. I'm a php web developer who dips his toe in and out of the turning PSDs into HTML/CSS for clients. For sometime I have considered making my own personal website.

**The Idea**

A rotating wheel that has the point of rotation at the bottom center of the web browser. See the image for a MUCH better depiction

[image]

**The Question**

What are my options/best choices that can be made here. Plain old HTML/CSS with JQuery? If so, does anyone have any examples of a similar site they could cite as a reference of how I would even get started? (perhaps even a tutorial?)

I apologise for the very basic nature of this question as I'm really just lost in which way would be the best to implement this

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Edit: http://www.nofrks.com/ is a similar idea, in principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has no support for drawing text at arbitrary angles, so there is no way to implement a decent rotation effect with. To achieve something like this you need to look either at the HTML5 Cavas element (poorly supported as of now), CSS3 (same as above) or Flash (bad for its own reasons).

Comment: He means that if you want your content to rotate, you will have to use only images. @Viruzzo are you sure jQuery doesn't allow this?

Comment: jQuery does little by itself, in this case it would only use CSS3. You can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105772/45-degree-angle-box-shadow-using-nothing-but-css for some insight (it uses Sandpaper), but these are not technologies ready for an actual production environment. Of course, the whole idea of rotating content is purely eye-candy at the expense of usability and accessibility, so he may not care).

Comment: Thanks for the comments viruzzo. Really helpful.

Comment: Was that sarcasm? Anyway, if you really want to implement such a design, it's entirely feasible but Flash is your only real option: everything else will die in front of IE's poor support of standards. Targeting mobile devices is out of the question anyway. Edit: I guess it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Raphaeljs, which is basically a Javascript library for charting/graphs, but you can definitely animate it....

here is a link to something you are looking for: http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html (works in ie8)

RaphaelJs website: http://raphaeljs.com/