# Non-clickable and empty area for transparent images

Tags: html, css

I am using a ribbon image on top right corner of my website with some transparent area, like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [bloomwebdesign.net](http://bloomwebdesign.net//wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Corner-Ribbon-Banner-005.jpg))</sub>

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"> <img src="/triangle.png" class="ribbon"></a>
```

Stylesheet:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1200;
width: 200px;
```

When I move the cursor into the transparent area of image, it shows pointer hand to open the link, but is there any way to make transparent area empty and non-clickable?

Comment: Please use `map/area` tag in such case. [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp)

Comment: I know, but i can"t understad how to make image map

Comment: By The way, my image is curvey!

Comment: [Here](http://www.image-maps.com/) is the site for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a square/rectangular portion of an image that you'd like to make clickable, you could create a separate `<a href="">` tag and use CSS to position and size it over the clickable area.

If it's NOT square/rectangular (it seems to be triangular from your question) then I would probably use a ***client-side image map***, as you can make the clickable region whatever shape you like.  There are several free tools online for creating image maps.  Try:

- http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap
- http://mappatool.com/
- http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: Yes, I think i should use image map becuase -o-transform is not compatible on older and other major browsers, image map support all old and modern browers and mobiles?

Comment: Yes, although they're not used terribly often in modern development, as far as I know they're supported in all old and modern browsers and mobiles.  See this Mozilla article for some details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS 3 rotations and use a horizontal image. When it is rotated the browser makes sure that only the image can be clicked.

```
-o-transform: rotate(40deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
transform: rotate(40deg);
```

nice example explained here http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/ which I got from this question [45 Degree Angle + Box Shadow - Using nothing but CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105772/45-degree-angle-box-shadow-using-nothing-but-css)